# regular expression doesn't work for html string with no spaces between tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I want to remove the **2nd** `<meta>` tag from this HTML string:

```
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="aaaa"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="bbbb"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="cccc">
```

Using this regular expression

```
/<meta http-equiv=[\"']?set-cookie[\"']? content=[\"']bbbb[\"'].*>/ig
```

removes not just the 2nd but also the 3rd meta tag. How would I modify this regular expressio to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that happens because `*` is greedy, and it will consume your string as much as possible

so change your regexp into

```
/<meta http-equiv=[\"']?set-cookie[\"']? content=[\"']bbbb[\"'].*?>/ig
```

note the `.*?` part at the end. The question mark after the `*` quantifier makes your regexp ungreedy, so it will consume the string until the first angular bracket has been retrieved.

Comment: @Obay: It makes the quantifier *lazy*, i.e. it tries to find the shortest match, not the longest. http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: @Obay: [Take a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification), the wiki explains the basics of how regexes work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DOM manipulation? Using regular expressions for more than *very simple* HTML [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/218196).

```
var head = document.createElement('head');
head.innerHTML = htmlString;
var meta = head.getElementsByTagName('meta')[1];
meta.parentNode.removeChild(meta);
htmlStr = head.innerHTML;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ruy3/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with plain regex. Here's my take on it:

```
var str = '<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="aaaa"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="bbbb"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="cccc">';
var r = /^<[^>]+>(<[^>]+>)/;
str.replace(r.exec(str)[1], ''); // <meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="aaaa"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="cccc">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use  :

```
/<meta[^>]*content="bbbb">/
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vZ9cE8)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

**CODE :**

```
var s='<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="bbbb"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="cccc"><meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="aaaa">';
var regex=/<meta[^>]*content="bbbb">/g;
var result=s.replace(regex,"")
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/Mx9rN/)**